# How to remove time from date in array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I am getting the data by push it into an array and I want to show that data on a page
I am using

```
$.each(data, function (i, o) {
                $scope.GetBlogDetailsar.push({ Id: o.id, Title: o.title, CategoryId: o.categoryId, SubCategoryId: o.subCategoryId, Image: o.image, MetaDescription: o.metaDescription, TotalLikes: o.totalLikes, TotalDislikes: o.totalDislikes, CreatedDate: o.createdDate, CategoryName: o.categoryName, SubCategoryName: o.subCategoryName });
            });
```

where GetBlogDetailsar is an array.

I am getting the desired data 
but the problem is I am getting the created date with time also I only need date to display
So how can I remove time from date.

I am getting

```
`2016-12-14T02:01:20.983 as created date`
```

I want only

```
2016-12-14
```

Comment: `"2016-12-14T02:01:20.983".split("T")[0]`

Comment: If you want it only in view then you can do: {{CreatedDate | date:'yyyy-mm-dd'}}. If you want the changed date format in controller for further processing then you need to inject the date filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this,

```
CreatedDate: o.createdDate.format("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Comment: Thanks Sir your solution is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You cant format date like so:

```
$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)
```

or

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

Can also use Moment.js to format date

Below is snippet

```js
var dateTime = moment('2016-12-14T02:01:20.983').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(dateTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```